# SOA Publishing Messages vs Calling Procedures

Tags: soa, rpc

The project I am working on is moving from an n-tier to a SOA architecture so I have been reading up on good SOA practices. I'm struggling to understand the dynamic between avoiding RPC style services in favor of event driven services, and the requirement of User Interfaces to retrieve data and do it speedily.

So for instance, ideally a SOA architecture would be composed of repeatable business process wherein you could simply publish a message onto an ESB which would handle finding the services that handle that message. So rather than executing a procedure called "Setup New User" which set out to do all the tasks related to new user setup, you would publish a message into the ESB that just contained the new user's details and had the appropriate document type "New User" and then the ESB would find services that handled that event that would then do whatever domain specific new user provisioning was required.

However, sometimes you just need data. Maybe you have a page that shows some list of user associated data. You can't just fire off a message into the ESB because you need data back and you need it now. Also, you aren't really triggering any business processes; you're just retrieving data from previously invoked business processes (the processes that caused the user to be associated with the data for instance).  So to give a concrete example, maybe I just want to see the list of 10 Netflix movies a user has watched recently.

How do you reconcile these disparate types of services in a single SOA system?

Comment: Without an ESB, you basically have Remove Procedure Calls and that's it. SOA is all about replacing that sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, the ESB is the glue between the various SOA *services*. You will always have a "service bus", it just may not be "enterprise" qualified. In your proposal, you're just using HTTP as your service bus, which ties you to request/response. Regardless, I'm not here to argue about ESB; my project is using one and I have no say in the matter. I'm in charge of designing some services, and my question is about service design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ESB, where event-driven approach is followed, you have all kinds of listeners, that detect events and act accordingly. These listeners may wait for the appearance of direct messages via some protocol at certain endpoint for example. No matter what the trigger is - a purely business event that starts a business process or a technical call that just needs to retrieve some data, it is still an event that is handled by the ESB. So you are not technically breaking the event-driven approach - it is enforced by your ESB solution. Moreover keep in mind SOA doesn't impose such limitation - you do not have to implement everything in event driven manner.

In your case (provided, you don't have a dedicated BPM solution in place), I'd identify and implement two kinds of services on two purely conceptual layers in the ESB:

- Technical services (the event is an incoming direct message for retrieval/modification of data), that can be either called directly by another system (via the ESB) or called by other process services.
- Process services on the top (business) layer that are being triggered in a event-driven way (using topic queue for example, where process services listen for their triggering event)

However, this may not be the most optimal approach. I've been discussing business processes in a dedicated business process layer versus process services in the ESB in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29255784/510615). Feel free to check it out, because it is kind of related with your question.

Comment: Your edit answers my question fairly well. The topic you link to helps elucidate it even further. Thank you very much.